# How do I print UTF-8 Character in Weblogic 12c Console?

Tags: encoding, character, weblogic

```
    String fullBriefDescription = "ຈົວ昨夜, 最高コンサ";
    System.out.println("fullBriefDescription Line 1094 "+fullBriefDescription);
    System.out.println("fullBriefDescription Length Line 1095 "+fullBriefDescription.length());
```

I have created a java file and run through Weblogic 12c as a Part of the project, but when I run the project and print output why I am getting "????? ???" instead of the above characters??

[image]

Please Help

Comment: Windows or Linux ?

Comment: Windows-Dev and Linux-Production

Comment: On Windows you can change the code page with the CHCP command : chcp 65001
See [this page](https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html)

Comment: I tried CHCP command unfortunately not working on my local machine! I deployed the code on Linux but nothing works.